# Установка PyQt5. Windows

Tags: python, qt

Доброго времени суток. Не получается установить PyQt5 через pip на Windows 32 bit и Python 3.4.3.

Выдает вот такую ошибку:
*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions:) No matching distribution found for PyQt5*

Через installer устанавливается нормально, но если посмотреть установленные пакеты через pip - то его там по прежнему нету

P.S. с PyQt4 такая же история

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте установить sip сначала

```
pip install sip --allow-external sip
```